# Differences resulted from calculating torque using different axis of rotation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, equilibrium

> A parked automobile of mass 1360 kg has a wheel base (distance between front and rear axles) of 305 cm. Its center of gravity is located 178 cm behind the front axle. Determine (a) the upward force exerted by the level ground on each of the front wheels (assumed the same) and (b) the upward force exerted by the level ground on each of the rear wheels (assumed the same).

I got that the force on the rear wheel is 3893 N, however, the solution says that the force on the front wheel is 3893 N. I checked my answer multiple times, but still can't find where I did wrong.

This is my solution, I used the center of gravity as the rotational axis for the torque calculations:

[image]

This is from the solution manual:

> (a) The net torque about the rear axle is (1360 kg)(9.8 m/s^2)(3.05 m−1.78 m)−Ff(3.05 m) =0, which has solutionFf= 5.55×103N.  Each of the front tires support half of this, or 2.77×103N.(b) The net torque about the front axle is (1360 kg)(9.8 m/s^2)(1.78 m)−Ff(3.05 m) = 0, whichhas solutionFf= 7.78×10^3N.  Each of the front tires support half of this, or 3.89×10^3N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Couldn't leave this as a comment)

There seems to be a typo in the solution manual's answer. The answers to both parts are listed as forces on the front wheels, whereas part b) of the question asks for the force on the rear wheels. The calculation used in the manual for b) refers to the torque about the front axle, for which there is no contribution from the front force. Hence, your answer is correct.

Regarding the choice of axes: There will be no difference in the answer if different axes are chosen to apply equilibrium conditions. In general, if the net force on a body is zero and the net torque is zero about any point $P$, it can be shown that the net torque is zero about every other point as well.